# Is it possible for a script to reference a line on a new record?

Tags: field, netsuite, suitescript

This relates to some older questions on SuiteScript 1.0. I've got a 2.0 script that has to be 2.0, so I can't use the old `nlapiGetLineItemValue` - it has to be `Record.getSublistValue(options)`. But I need it to get the line value on a new, unsaved record `BeforeSubmit`.

It keeps returning "getSublistValue" is not defined in object, and checking NetSuite Field Explorer confirms that the unsaved record has no defined lines.
The same applies to `AfterSubmit`.

So is there any work around, or is it even possible, to reference the line item value when the record is being created?

ADDING SOME CODE, WHERE THE QUESTION APPLIES:

```
var recNew = context.newRecord
var ItemID = recNew.getSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'items',
    fieldId: 'itemid',
});
var listIDs = ["6646", "17745", "17945", "21349"];

var a_filters = [];
a_filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter(ItemID, null, 'anyof', listIDs));
{
   // an action
   }
```

Comment: It'll be helpful if you can share your full code, or at least the relevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getSublistValue requires you to pass the line number.

```
var recNew = context.newRecord 
for (var x =0; x< recNew.getLineCount({sublistId:'item'}); x++) {
     var ItemID = recNew.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'item', line: x });
     // DO STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
if(scriptContext.type == 'edit'){
    var recNew = scriptContext.newRecord
        recNew.getSublistValue(options)
}
```

Comment: vVinceth, I just added some code as erictgrubaugh suggested, with your suggestion added in - now getting an error that I'm missing a required argument. I don't have the context.Type mentioned anywhere, because I need it on both Edit and Create (create particularly). Has that got something to do with it?

Comment: Thanks for that @vVinceth - only I'm now getting an error "JS_EXCEPTION". I'll plug the whole script extract, and error message, into a comment, or maybe the question. I can't see where I've gone wrong, its got me baffled.

Comment: `if (scriptContext.type == 'create') {
   var recNew = scriptContext.newRecord
   var itemCount = recNew.getLineCount({
    sublistId: 'item'
   });
   for (var i=0;i<=itemCount;i++){
   var ItemID = recNew.getSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'item',
    line: i
   });

   var listIDs = ["6646", "17745", "17945", "21349"];

   var filters = [];
    filters.push(new
     search.createFilter({
    name: ItemID,
    operator: 'ANYOF',
    values: listIDs
   })
   );`

Comment: JS_EXCEPTION
{userFacing=true, stack=[Ljava.lang.Object;@6f0fe897, requireType=define, requireMap={originalName=_$Y$, parentMap=null, isDefine=true, prefix=null, unnormalized=false, name=_$Y$, id=_$Y$, url=_$Y$.js}, cause={name=A1Error, notifyOff=false, message=Unable to Process due to A1, sorry!}, type=error.SuiteScriptError, message=Unable to Process due to A1, sorry!, toJSON=gen.api.rhino.v2x.error@6c1df477, requireModules=[Ljava.lang.Object;@368b2783, name=A1Error, notifyOff=false, toString=org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction@3ea6fd2b, id=}